# Decrement value if value after reduction is not less than 0 Prisma

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, prisma

I'm looking for a method to decrement a data, if the data after the reduction is not less than zero then the data is saved to the DB, else throw some error. I've been looking for things in the docs but there is no any solution using a transaction for this method and I'm quite skeptical about if there is a concurrent request.

Can anyone help me giving the best method or solution to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into the same thing, I came across this interactive transactions mode in Prisma docs where it allows to pass an async function to `$transactions` api so that custom application logic can be introduced between database transactions. This might help, but be aware that it is in preview.

Find link here, [Interactive Transactions (In Preview)](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/performance-and-optimization/prisma-client-transactions-guide#interactive-transactions-in-preview)

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue and the solution, up until now, seems to be the use of interactive transactions.